# Docker For Windows CE: Kubernetes: Unable to connect to the server eof

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

I simply cannot find a solution for this " Unable to connect to the server eof", hopefully we solve this and it helps somebody in future, when searching to fix this issue. I tried to include all information in the screenshot. Let me know if more information is required.

I have tried to add the information requested, let me know if theres anything else you need or want me to try.

[image: CMD Information]

[image: More Information]

Comment: Could you please share the output of following command:
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c kubedns

Comment: Please see updated question with the requested information.

Comment: I'm using exactly the same Docker Desktop version on my Windows 10 Pro client, and do not observe similar issue. I have updated your question with more precise instruction on how to retrieve logs from faulty component of your Kubernetes installation.  The printscreen you attached shows that command was not executed properly (it`s incomplete).

Comment: Ok, I see you problem now, you cannot even execute kubectl get pod, to get the kube-dns pod name, before getting its logs. I will update my edits, and suggest other way of getting these log files, directly from default docker log storage.

Comment: Ok,let me know how I can get the logs needed to fix this issue.

Comment: @Optimus Prime have solution below helped ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get into logs of kube-dns docker container directly as below:

1. Enable 'Show system containers' option in Docker Desktop settings: 
   [image]
2. Check if kube-dns container was ever run:

> docker ps -a --filter name=k8s_kubedns_kube-dns --format "table
>   {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}"

You should see similar command output to this:

> CONTAINER ID IMAGE
>   9009731e183d 80cc5ea4b547

3. Get kube-dns container logs with:

docker logs {your_container_id} --tail 100

Comment: Under the Kubernetes tab, Show system containers(advanced) is disabled. I cannot select the checkbox. "Enable Kubernetes" and "Deploy Docker Stacks" is ticked.

Comment: Please try to stop docker deamon first from system tray, before ticking this checkbox.

Comment: I went into the services menu and stopped "Docker-For-Windows" but the checkbox "Show system containers(advanced)" is still disabled. Please note that all 3 checkboxes under the kubernetes tab is disabled.

Comment: Well, it doesn`t look good. Can you please verify quickly if your Docker is functioning correctly by running basic container with: docker run hello-world. Maybe worth Restarting Docker or even using option: Reset to factory defaults.

Comment: Docker is working fine, I managed to pull the nginx image from docker hub and run the server locally on localhost:8088.

Comment: Where are you with this issue, did you manage to do some progress ?

Comment: No, but docker is working, I can run containers etc etc, I still cannot check show system containers and I still get the same Unable to connect to server EOF error.

Comment: I did encountered recently the same error message on fresh cluster installation, and it had to do with kubernetes being unable to start up one of the main critical components (kube-apiserver). I needed to correct manually server run options.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error (with Docker Desktop on Windows 11, using wsl2), and the solution for me was to use the Settings page (in DD), then choose "Kubernetes" on the left, then chose "reset kubernetes cluster". That warned that all stacks and k8s resources would be deleted, but as nothing else had worked for me (and I wasn't worry about losing much), I tried it, and it did solve the problem.

FWIW, k8s had been working fine for me for some time. It was just that one day I found I was getting this error. I searched and searched and found lots of folks asking about it but not getting answers, let alone this answer (even here). To be clear, I had tried restarting Docker Desktop, restarting the host machine, even downloading and installing an available DD update (I was only a bit behind), and nothing worked. But the reset did.

I realize some may fear losing something, but again it worked and was worth it for me. Hope that may help others.